# Silverlight Out of Browser without installing?

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser, emulation

Is there any way that I can have the user run my silverlight application with the use of sllauncher.exe and the emulate option from my server?

This is what I currently have:

```
sllauncher /emulate:"Prog.xap" /origin:"http://domain.com/Prog.xap"
```

The only problem with this is that it only works if there is a local file, is there any way that I don't need anything to be downloaded on the user end?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. XAP file always needs to download in client side before execution.

Comment: OK but whenever I run the command above, it will just display the local xap file, not the updated web xap file, I have tried the /overwrite argument but that didn't do anything